# "Crudy By Design" with a third party API

Tags: php, laravel

Following the **"Crudy By Design"**

I am consuming an API which had many POST requests, and each of them require slightly different parameters that I need to pass into.

My go to solution would be creating a POST for each of the endpoints I need but in this case I want to follow the "crudy" design pattern.

I can make a "`store`" route that accepts "`/{type}`" and inside there I can check "`if $type === 'xxxx' do X`"

Although now say theres 15 POST requests, and I need to validate each one. I just made my controller function about 100-150 lines of code by having to wrap it in a `try/catch`, calling `$this->validate`, then returning errors. [The actual API gets called in the service and I have a service layer beyond that].

How does this new "crudy" design benefit now if I just created a new bloated controller function? Which seems painful to manage now to?

I initially would make a new POST route for each. Doesn't this violate the SRP principal bloating one function like that?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but maybe make a factory to build the correct payload, based on your input, for the API you are consuming

Comment: @krisgjika Crudy by design is a design where you separate logic into multiple controllers to keep it "CRUD" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI&t=3s